# link static library into dynamic labrary in gcc Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, linker

I have a lot of static libraries that wrote on "c++" under 32 bits platform Linux. Now i need to compile "c" dynamic library in 64 bits platform Linux with my functionality from c++.
Can someone tell me the best way to do this. I know that i should put all functions prototypes into `extern "C"` logic but should I have to compile static libraries with `"-fPIC"` key . Which keys i have to use in `gcc` compiler to link my c++ libraries ? any help will be appreciate

Thanks a lot

Comment: do you have the 32 Bits in source or just as static binaries

Comment: yep i have all sources

Comment: one thing you definitely need is to use 'g++' at the link command. it will add all needed c++ libraries and qualifiers (unless you want to do it manually). You should also compile and link your code with '-m32'.

Answer (score 0):

This link is usefull for creating the libs :

```
http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/shared-libraries-linux-gcc.html
```

and this is for mixing C and C++

```
https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp
```

Comment: thanks for helping, this is my steps to resolve my task:

Comment: 1 compile all cpp libs with -fPIC and -m64 flags

Comment: 3. add into linkage string gcc -shared -xc++ -lstdc++ -shared-libgcc and my static libs